# Binding controls to a collection of objects

Tags: c#, collections, binding

I need help with data binding. Imagine this situation. I have two classes, one named Isotope, another named Photon. Class Isotope contains BindingList Photons.  I also have a static class StaticVariables, where I put BindingList Isotopes. Now, I want to make a form which will allow me to browse the list of isotopes. I created a combobox CBIsotopes, that I bound to StaticVariables.Isotopes:

```
 CBIsotope.DataSource = StaticVariables.Isotopes;
 CBIsotope.ValueMember = "IsotopeName";
 CBIsotope.DisplayMember = "IsotopeName";
```

So far, everything works. Now I want to create a datagridview DGVPhotons that will show all the photons of the selected isotope. My first instinct was to do something along the way of

```
DGVPhotons.DataSource = StaticVariables.ListOfIsotopes.Photons
```

which of course, doesn't work. Another thing I tried is to use SelectedItem property of the ComboBox:

(1)

```
DGVPhotons.DataSource = (CBIsotope.SelectedItem as Isotope).Photons;
```

This works, but not as well as I would like. If I do it on load time, nothing happens, because ComboBox is empty. If I do it when an item is actually selected in ComboBox, then it works, but as I change the selection in ComboBox, DataGridView stays the same. The solution would be to put line (1) in SelectedIndexChanged of the ComboBox, but it seems like a brute force method to me, and I feel that my approach is fundamentally wrong... Is there some more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the key here is to use `DataBind` solution. After you change `source` of your element don't forget to use `DataBind` method after, in order to bind new data.

And also, on `PageLoad` event, don't forget to use `IsPostBack` sign in order to initialize page only when request is handled for the first time.